# Why does upgrading to 12.04 on an OpenVZ VPS warn that the kernel size is 0?

Tags: server, upgrade, virtualization, release-upgrade, openvz

When I tried to upgrade my server to ubuntu 12.04, it gave this message, but the upgrade process will continue :

```
 WARNING:root:estimate_kernel_size_in_boot() returned '0'?
```

This is a VPS server on openvz. I just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 without any problems. But what to do now?

Comment: Can you access a shell?

Comment: @Mitch Yes its working. I tried to upgrade through it. I didn't upgrade to 12.04... cancelled it after seeing the error!

Comment: Can you include the output of **sudo fdisk -l**

Comment: @Mitch It says "cannot open /proc/partitions"

Comment: Do you have other OS's on you system

Comment: @Mitch Nope... its a VPS... Inside OpenVZ

Comment: @Mitch : `fdisk` fails because OpenVZ has one single "simulated filesystem", no partitions or anything.

Comment: I'm getting this too on my TrimSlice, a tegra 2 dev board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But what to do now?

Continue. The warning is expected, since OpenVZ VPSs **do not have their own kernels** -- they operate on the physical host's kernel. OpenVZ is more like an enhanced `chroot` rather than a true virtual machine in that respect.

### Important - if your running kernel is less than 2.6.24

Please check your current kernel version with `uname -r`. If it is **less than 2.6.24**, the upgrade **will** fail half-way with a `glibc` error. That happens because the `glibc` included by default with 12.04 requires a minimum 2.6.24 kernel -- `glibc` are the critical C libraries used by *every* application.

At that point, you will need the instructions [from this answer], as pasted below:

---

I've set up a [PPA containing a recompiled libc](https://launchpad.net/%7Eizx/+archive/ovz-libc/+packages) which is compiled to work on **2.6.18** or newer (please check `uname -r`!), and it should override the current libc provided by Precise. Just add *ppa:izx/ovz-libc*, update, and it *should* let you get past this. Specifically, something like this:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:izx/ovz-libc
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
do-release-upgrade
```

and continue on until the upgrade completes successfully. I highly recommend NOT replacing any changed or non-existent config files.

I will be keeping the ppa updated as and when libc is updated upstream. The PPA package includes a pin so that it will only be updated when the new fixed libc is available on the PPA, not when it first appears in the official repositories.

Comment: It worked but it took my server offline :P There were some issues with openvz and 12.04. Thanks to my host's support, we fixed it :D

Comment: Just gave this a go but I'm still getting gcc errors when trying to run apt-get -f install:

    gcc: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by gcc)

Comment: This PPA didn't work for Virtuozzo at least. Testing from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 it fails to me with: "/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by locale)"